# Select with Nested table omitting duplicate values

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have two tables.
T1

```
--------------------------
|IDT1|DESCR     |  VALUE |
--------------------------
|   1|TEST 1    |     100|
|   2|TEST 2    |      80|
--------------------------
```

T2

```
-----------
|IDT2|IDT1|
-----------
|   1|   1|
|   2|   1|
|   3|   2|
-----------
```

The field T2.IDT1 is foreign key of T1.IDT1.
I need to omit the duplicate values of T1 table (only), like the second row in the below result.

```
----------------------------
|IDT1|DESCR   |IDT2|  VALUE|
----------------------------
|   1|TEST 1  |   1|    100|
|    |        |   2|       |
|   2|TEST 2  |   3|     80|
----------------------------
```

I am using firebird 2.5.

Comment: Show us what you have tried please.

Comment: This type of data transformation -- although possible in SQL -- is much better done at the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with firebird, but if this was an Oracle DB, you could try this:

```
select
  t1.idt1,
  t1.descr,
  t2.idt2,
  t1.value
from (
  select
    t2.idt2 idt2,
    case
      when lag(t2.idt1) over (order by t2.idt1, t2.idt2) = t2.idt1 theN null
      else t2.idt1
    end idt1
  from t2
) t2
left outer join t1
  on t1.idt1 = t2.idt1
order by 3;
```

You can test that here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd647/10)

Comment: Firebird doesn't have window functions yet (they are available in Firebird 3 beta).